# What does "Religion in the Making" mean?

Tags: meaning

I have found a book titled *[Religion in the Making](http://www.alfrednorthwhitehead.wwwhubs.com/ritm1.htm)*.

What does it mean in full English?

Comment: "... In the Making" suggests the historical and social processes associated with the "growth" of particular religious beliefs and tenets, that is, their popularity and their ability to become enmeshed with Culture and Identity, how people see themselves, and identify the "Other".

Comment: This book consists of a series of four lectures, given by Alfred Whitehead in 1926 Boston.  1926 was just one year after the Scopes Monkey Trial, a famous clash between American religious fundamentalism (as represented by William Jennings Bryan) and American atheism (as represented by the ACLU's Clarence Darrow) over whether Tennessee school teachers could teach the theory of evolution.

Comment: I'm definitely not an active users of this SE, but why has this post been downvoted? The question is clear and I guess it's valid, I'm not sure why the OP asks what it means "in full English", but since this is a site for English learners, I guess we can just parse it as "what it means" and that should be ok. So… why the downvote?

Answer (score 2):

"In the making" means that someone is building/creating it.

So, "religion in the making" refers (maybe methaphorically, that depends on the book) to a religion that is being created/designed/written or maybe that it is evolving.